# Xamarin Forms How to add Header for ListView on Code Behind

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using **Xamarin.Forms**, I am trying to add `header` for `listView` already Created on Code behind,I am trying to add Number of rows(users) on list as the `header` how I can do that,
Check the following code for my `ListView`:

```
UsersListView = new ListView()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HasUnevenRows = true,
                ItemsSource = Users //Users is List<string>()           
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list view has a Header property that you can set. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Headers_and_Footers as text or as headertemplate.

What you need to do is just monitor changes in your users list and put the Users.Count in the header property.

Comment: I add Header="Test" and it doesn't appear

Comment: I believe this is the solution but Header doesn't appear on my case

Comment: Maybe first try to add static text, to see how it goes... if not take a look at the official example https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WorkingWithListview/WorkingWithListview/HeaderFooter

Comment: This should work, can you update your question with the code you have tried that isn't working?